# Sum of two independent uniform random variables in different regions

Tags: probability

If X is uniformly distributed on (−1, 0) and Y is uniformly distributed on (0, 1). How do we calculate the PDF of Z which is the sum of X and Y i.e Z=X+Y.

What should be the limits of integration in this case as X and Y are not defined on the same region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to integrate wrt $x$ over the region where: $(-1< x<0)$ *and* $(0<z-x<1)$

So that is where: $(\max\{-1,z-1\}<x<\min\{z,0\})$ *and* $(-1<z<1)$.

Which is partitioned into: $((-1<x<z)\cap(-1<z<0)$ *or* $(z-1<x<0)\cap(0\leqslant z<1)$

> $$\begin{align}f_Z(z) & = \int_\Bbb R f_X(x)~f_Y(z-x)\operatorname d x \\[2ex]& = \int_\Bbb R \mathbf 1_{x\in(-1;0)}\cdot\mathbf 1_{{\small(}z-x{\small)}\in(0;1)}\operatorname d x \\[2ex] & = \mathbf 1_{z\in(-1;1)}\cdot \int_{\max\{-1,z-1\}}^{\min\{z,0\}}\operatorname d x\\[2ex] & = \mathbf 1_{z\in(-1;0)}\cdot \int_{-1}^{z}\operatorname d x~+~ \mathbf 1_{z\in[0;1)}\cdot \int_{z-1}^{0}\operatorname d x \\[2ex]&= (1-\lvert z\rvert)\cdot\mathbf 1_{z\in(-1;1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't have a paper on hand to check the calculation, but that PDF doesn't look like it integrates to $1$. Though I could be misunderstanding your notation for the indicator function..

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 (1-\lvert z\rvert)\operatorname d z~=~1$

Comment: You have a $+$ instead of a $-$ in your answer above (which you've corrected in your comment).

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you.